# Deploy Rails app using capstrano from inside a docker container

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, capistrano

I managed to dockerize my rails application for development and it works great. Before this I had a deploy setup using Capistrano. Now I would like to try and deploy using the same Capistrano but executed from within the docker container. My question is can i use the same ssh key from my host machine or should I generate a new key inside the container? The last option does not sound good to me since it would have to be recreated when the container gets destroyed. I am aware that in the long run I would probably be better off setting the production server to run docker and install through docker machine but so far I just like to keep the setup I have already on production.

Anyone else have tried this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should link your devices ssh key into the container (as long as the container is not accessible from network). Additionally to your argument, you can more easily share your image with others as they are able to just link their key themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your SSH key into the container at runtime.

`docker run -v /path/to/host/ssh-key:/path/to/container/ssh-key <image> <command>`

`ssh-key` will be available in the container at `/path/to/container/ssh-key`